# RabbitMQ delayed exchange plugin does not work after virtual ip switch

Tags: rabbitmq-exchange, spring-rabbit

I'm working on a project which involved rabbitmq to receive and process information. I have setup a virtual IP under which all the actual instances of rabbitmq function. Applications connect to this virtual IP. RabbitMQ cluster has ha set to all.

During one such instance the master instance of rabbitmq hung which caused the another instance to become the active/master participant and all the queues were shifted to the new instance but the queues bound to rabbitmq exchange stopped working. Application is not able to publish or receive any messages. Though the management plugin still shows consumers connected to the queue.

Below is the startup log for the now master/active rabbitmq instance

```
Server startup complete; 7 plugins started.
* rabbitmq_management
* rabbitmq_web_dispatch
* webmachine
* mochiweb
* amqp_client
* rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
* rabbitmq_management_agent
```

Below is the context information for applications bound to rabbitmq for the delayed message exchange

```
<rabbit:topic-exchange name="DELAY-EXCHANGE" id="delayExchange" delayed="true" durable="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="PRO_Q1" pattern="q1_delayed" />
            <rabbit:binding queue="PRO_Q2" pattern="q2_delayed" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

Does anyone has an idea as to why the plugin stopped working and the applications are not able to publish or consume from the exchange.